# rewrite URL for PUT request

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, put

I changed the way my URL are working on my server.
It is now `www.myserver.com/service` instead of `www.myserver.com/test/service`

I have added a RedirectMatch 301 to my Apache conf file to redirect any access to `www.myserver.com/test` to `www.myserver.com/`.

I am receiving file to this server via an HTTP PUT at this URL for example :
`www.myserver.com/test/service/put/myfile.xml`

The server sending the file don't handle the 301 HTTP status code so the files didn't arrived anymore.

Is there a way to rewrite the URL when it is a PUT Request in order to don't miss any file?

Thanks,

Benjamin

---

UPDATE :

Here is the RewriteLog content after applying this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =PUT
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) /$1 [PT]
```

log :

```
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f378538a828/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/service/put/myfile.xml
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f378538a828/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/test/(.*)' to uri '/test/service/put/myfile.xml'
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f378538a828/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='PUT' pattern='=PUT' => matched
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f378538a828/initial] (2) rewrite '/test/service/put/myfile.xml' -> '/service/put/myfile.xml'
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f378538a828/initial] (2) forcing '/service/put/myfile.xml' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f3785393858/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /service/put/myfile.xml
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f3785393858/subreq] (3) applying pattern '^/test/(.*)' to uri '/service/put/myfile.xml'
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [16/May/2010:06:33:40 +0000] [www.myserver.com/sid#7f378508aa30][rid#7f3785393858/subreq] (1) pass through /service/put/myfile.xml
```

---

UPDATE 2 :

Apache configuration :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "/etc/httpd/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =PUT
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) /$1 [PT]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/(.*)$ http://www.myserver.com/$1
AliasMatch ^/style/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/style/$1"
AliasMatch ^/js/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/js/$1"
AliasMatch ^/min/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/min/$1"
AliasMatch ^/downloads/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/downloads/$1"
AliasMatch ^/images/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/images/$1"
AliasMatch ^/chart/(.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/graphs/$1"
AliasMatch ^(/.*)?$ "/var/www/test/www/index.php$1"

<Directory "/var/www/test">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is, with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =PUT
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: mod_rewrite will not issue any 302 or 301 redirect?

Comment: No, unless you tell it to (or you give a full URL).

Comment: With this mod_rewrite rule I am getting a 405 HTTP error status saying :

"The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /test/service/put/myfile.xml"

when I try to send a PUT request to my server instead of the 301 HTTP status.
How can I verify that the rewrite is done correctly?
After the RewriteRule I am doing AliasMatch. Will they still work if the rewrite happen?
Thanks!

Comment: Tru adding the PT (passthru) flag to the rewriterule: RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) /$1 [PT]

Comment: Here is the apache access_log : XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - user [16/May/2010:06:12:25 +0000] "PUT /test/service/put/myfile.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 1759 "-" "-"

Comment: The log looks file. Show your AliasMatch directive and increase the logging verbosity of apache itself. Better yet, substitute the AliasMatch directive for a rewrite rule.

Comment: I increased the logging verbosity of apache but nothing useful shows up when I try to PUT a file to my server.
I have added my aliasMatch directives in my question.

Comment: So you pass the requested URI to /var/www/test/www/index.php as path info? I don't know if that's supposed to work... Try aliasing the directory where index.php (say Alias /mydir/ "/var/www/test/www/") and then change the rewrite rule to RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) /mydir/index.php/$1 [PT]

Comment: How can I substitute the AliasMatch directive for a rewrite rule?
What would be the purpose of this?
Will this solve my problem?
Thanks